# How can I put the keys of an array in a ChoiceType element for Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to build a form that I will implement in a Twig template. For that, I'm using some HTML elements. One of them is The ChoiceType from Symfony component. I've created an array that i pass to the `add` method. 
My wish is to display the keys in the value attribute and each value of the array in the label, thing I have failed to do

```
protected $lsa_types = array(
    'B' => 'Boolean',
    'D' => 'Date',
    'F' => 'Float',
    'I' => 'Integer',
    'L' => 'List',
    'S' => 'String',
    'T' => 'Text',
);

$form->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => $this->lsa_types,
            'choice_label' => function ($value) {
                return $value;
            },
            'choice_value' => function ($key) {
                return $key;
            },
            'required' => true));
```

Comment: the problem here is you dont have $value | $key from the array that you are trying to pass to the closure, you might want to re-work on your array to look something like $array = [
["key"=>"B", "value"=>"Boolean"],
["key"=>"D", "value"=>"Date"],...
];
and then you can pass to closure like,  ... "choice_label" => function($data) {return $data['value']; } and so on

Comment: Try to flip your array and using `"choices_as_values" => true` as option of your ChoiceType

Comment: `choices_as_values` is deprecated since the third version of symfony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as @Massimiliano commented, but leave out the `choices_as_values`, `choice_label` & `choice_value` options:

```
protected $lsa_types = array(
    'B' => 'Boolean',
    'D' => 'Date',
    'F' => 'Float',
    'I' => 'Integer',
    'L' => 'List',
    'S' => 'String',
    'T' => 'Text',
);

...

$choices = array_flip($this->lsa_types);

$form
    ->add(
        'type', 
        ChoiceType::class, 
        array(
            'choices' => $choices,
            'required' => true
        )
    )
;
```